# core data warning in console

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm getting this warning output to the console whenever I write to core data

```
CPSqliteStatementPerform: attempt to write a readonly database for UPDATE ddd.ext_container SET orig_date_modified = (SELECT date_modified FROM container WHERE pid=container_pid) WHERE orig_date_modified=0
CPSqliteStatementReset: attempt to write a readonly database for UPDATE ddd.ext_container SET orig_date_modified = (SELECT date_modified FROM container WHERE pid=container_pid) WHERE orig_date_modified=0
```

Everything seems to work ok, I dont get any crashes or anything like that, its just worrying.
Anyone know what this means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944281/why-am-i-getting-this-cpsqlitestatementperform-error-in-xcode-console and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159079/cryptic-sqlite-console-output-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

Have you initialized the persistent store as readonly? That would cause this general type of message.

Have you tried to access the store via SQLite bypassing the Core Data stack? If so, you probably corrupted the store.