# Why am I getting this CPSqliteStatementPerform error in xcode console

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I am getting the following errors in the xcode console, but I don't know what read only data base it is complaining about:

```
CPSqliteStatementPerform: attempt to write a readonly database for UPDATE ddd.ext_container SET orig_date_modified = (SELECT date_modified FROM container WHERE pid=container_pid) WHERE orig_date_modified=0
CPSqliteStatementReset: attempt to write a readonly database for UPDATE ddd.ext_container SET orig_date_modified = (SELECT date_modified FROM container WHERE pid=container_pid) WHERE orig_date_modified=0
```

The following code executes just prior to the error:

```
MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
NSArray *array = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];
playlists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[playlists addObject:@"new playlist"];
NSLog(@"%@", [playlists objectAtIndex:0]);

int numPlaylists = 1;
for (MPMediaPlaylist *arrayItem in array) {
    NSLog(@"Got here");
```

The NSLog prints 'new playlist'

Then the CPSqliteStatementPerform: and the CPSqliteStatementReset: errors print immediately after the for loop is initialized.

Then NSLog prints 'Got here'.

What read-only database am I writing and how do I correct this?

Comment: Jeff, Did you ever find out what caused this. I have a similar problem and have not been able to find a solution. Bill

Comment: No, I never figured it out. Still hoping that someone has a solution.

Comment: I was just thinking that maybe it throws an error when you put MPMediaItems into an array because you are trying to copy them? Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The device seems to think that you are trying to write to those locations. I am doing a similar project and opened up my iPhone's console in Organizer to see what was going on.
Here are the lines that show up when I try to get properties of MPMediaItems:

```
May 27 22:11:04 unknown sandboxd[2512] <Notice>: QueryTesting(2510) deny file-write-mode /private/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/iTunes/iTunes Library.itlp/Library.itdb
May 27 22:11:04 unknown sandboxd[2512] <Notice>: QueryTesting(2510) deny file-write-data /private/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/iTunes/iTunes Library.itlp/Library.itdb
May 27 22:11:04 unknown sandboxd[2512] <Notice>: QueryTesting(2510) deny file-write-data /private/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/iTunes/iTunes Library.itlp/Dynamic.itdb
May 27 22:11:04 unknown sandboxd[2512] <Notice>: QueryTesting(2510) deny file-write-data /private/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/iTunes/iTunes Library.itlp/Extras.itdb
May 27 22:11:04 unknown sandboxd[2512] <Notice>: QueryTesting(2510) deny file-write-data /private/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/iTunes/iTunes Library.itlp/DBTemp/ddd.itdbm
```

Even though I'm just checking what the values are, it thinks I'm trying to write there. Possible bug?

EDIT:
This is a bug, as discussed here --->> https://devforums.apple.com/message/428584#428584

Answer (score 1):

This started happening to my app, when i started to use a Settings.bundle root.plist file.
When i remove this it disappears.

Think there is something wrong with NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.......

For now i'm just going to ignore this message, and send an update of my app to apple.

Comment: Hmm. Thats interesting. But unfortunately, I kind of need the Settings.bundle.