# Cryptic SQLite console output in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios4, console, mpmediaquery

When running my program to query the iPod library of my iPhone, I get the following output in the console:

CPSqliteStatementPerform: attempt to write a readonly database for UPDATE ddd.ext_container SET orig_date_modified = (SELECT date_modified FROM container WHERE pid=container_pid) WHERE orig_date_modified=0

I have disabled everything that outputs to the console so it isn't as if I am having an error with NSLog. What is going on here and how can I fix it. I'll include the overall class source code that I am calling, along with the class that does the work (sorry for posting it all:

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *) makeQuery {

MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init]; //query iPod library
NSString *facebookIDKey = @"Facebook ID";
NSString *genericFacebookID = @"1234567890";
NSMutableDictionary *organizedSongData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:genericFacebookID forKey:facebookIDKey];
NSArray *allSongs = [query collections];

//only add those songs which have not
//been played since last login
for (MPMediaItem *recent in allSongs) {
    NSDate *lastPlayed = [recent valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate];
    int songCounter = 1;
    BOOL uploadInfo = [[PlayedSinceLastLogin alloc] initWithLastPlayedDateOfSong:lastPlayed];
    if (uploadInfo == YES) {
        //adds songs into
        [organizedSongData addEntriesFromDictionary: [MakeDicForSongInfo initWithMPMediaItem:recent andSongNumber:songCounter]];
        songCounter++;
    }
}

return organizedSongData;
}
```

Here is the actual brunt of the work, done in the MakeDicForSongInfo:

```
+(NSDictionary *) initWithMPMediaItem:(MPMediaItem *) song andSongNumber: (int)songCount{


//Create & initialize NSStrings for keys
//Create NSArray to hold keys

NSString *songKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Song Title", songCount];
NSString *albumKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Album", songCount];
NSString *artistKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Artist", songCount];
NSString *artistIDKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Artist Persistent ID", songCount];
NSString *lastPlayedKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Late Played Date", songCount];
NSString *genreKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Genre", songCount];
NSString *ratingKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i User Rating", songCount];
NSString *playCountKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Play Count", songCount];

NSArray *propertyKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:songKey, albumKey, artistKey, artistIDKey, 
                        lastPlayedKey, genreKey, ratingKey, playCountKey, nil];

//Create & initialize NSStrings to hold song property information
//Create NSArray to hold the values

NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSString *albumName = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
NSString *artistName = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
NSString *artistID = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtistPersistentID];
NSString *lastPlayed = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate];
NSString *genre = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyGenre];
NSString *userRating = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyRating];
NSString *playCount = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount];

NSArray *propertyValues = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:songTitle, albumName, artistName, artistID, 
                           lastPlayed, genre, userRating, playCount, nil];

//Create NSDictionary to store information, initializing it with
//above data, then returning the resulting dictionary

NSDictionary *songInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:propertyValues forKeys:propertyKeys];

return songInfo;
}
```

Could it be something in accessing all that Media information that spooks the iPhone?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944281/why-am-i-getting-this-cpsqlitestatementperform-error-in-xcode-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in iOS 4.3 and is addressed in this devforum at Apple:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/428584#428584